# Тормозит IDLE. (окно при перетаскивании)

Tags: python, idle

Подергивается окно *IDLE* при перетаскивании. Компьютер мощный: i7, 8GB RAM, видеокарта r9270x. А окошко глючит, как будто комп не тянет.

Запустил *IDLE* в виде единого процесса. Из командной строки с добавлением флага -n:

```
idle.py -n
```

*IDLE* запустился и работает без тормозов. Но при таком запуске пишет предупреждение:

> WARNING: Running IDLE without a Subprocess is deprecated
>   and will be removed in a later version. See Help/IDLE Help
>   for details

С чем связаны тормоза, и стоит ли обращать внимание на это предупреждение?

В книге Лутца описывается похожая проблема. Но там описывается проблема соединения/запуска. А у меня с процессом что-то не так.
Вот текст из книги:

> Если возникают ошибки соединения, попробуйте запустить IDLE в виде 
>   единого процесса. Из-за того что для нормальной работы IDLE необходимо 
>   поддерживать взаимодействие между пользовательским процессом и гра-
>   фическим интерфейсом среды разработки, на определенных платформах 
>   могут проявляться проблемы с запуском (особенно часто проблема с запу-
>   ском встречается на некоторых машинах windows). Если вам доведется 
>   столкнуться с такими ошибками, попробуйте запустить IDLE из командной 
>   строки, что вынудит ее запуститься в виде единственного процесса и позво-
>   лит избежать проблем с поддержанием соединения: для принудительного 
>   запуска в этом режиме используйте флаг –n.

Comment: Если вы пишете вопрос-ответ, то оставьте информацию, касающуюся вопроса, только в самом вопросе. Сейчас получается, что вы решили проблему ещё в самом вопросе и просто вынесли эту фразу в ответ.

Comment: @AntonKirienko, так переформулируйте вопрос. иначе ваш «ответ» в нынешнем виде не является на него ответом.

Comment: Я просто удалю ответ. Меня сбило с толку предложение самому ответить на свой вопрос. Больше не буду так делать.